# Переименовывание пространства имен

Tags: c#, resharper

Создал пустой проект, в нем есть класс Program.cs он по умолчанию помещается в пространство имен с названием проекта, после переименования проекта переименовываю это пространство имен, но решарпер постоянно предлагает сменить пространство имен на старое (то что было изначально).Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить ?

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять в свойствах проекта Application → Default namespace. Судя по всему, Решарпер смотрит именно туда.